# Scanning in strings into a 2D array in C

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

I need to take an input of 20 words entered by the user put those into a 2D array and print that out
my current code is

```
char array2[20][20];
int i;
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    printf("enter a word\n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]",array2[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<colsize2;i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<rowsize2;j++)
    {
        printf("%c",array2[i][j]);
    }
}
```

(I have no idea what  %[^\n] is but it works better than %c or %s)

there are no compiler errors and the program will run but when it prints the array after all the words have been entered all I get is complete garbage

like

aȪ(M▒awn-US▒       e▒(<▒▒t/▒▒▒(5h▒tr:▒(
                                                qh▒tdle__000
HW5.exe▒`wauld▒(▒&Oe,▒*a▒+a▒▒

so much so that it takes a bit of scrolling to get back to the start of my program

I do have more in this program that's not in my question but I'm 99% sure it wouldn't mess with what I have here but if you do want to see the rest just ask

I literally just started programming so I don't know diddly squat about it yet so if you could keep that in mind when you answer also this is for a school assignment so it doesn't need to be perfect it just has to get the job done

thanks to whoever answers this I've been grappling with this for hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your array to 0:

```
char array2[20][20] = { 0 } ;
```

And then print the string not every character:

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    printf("%s",array2[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked although apparently I have a bug called GCC bug 53119 (it's on another Stackoverflow question) it still works but I'm getting a compiler error but I can figure it out, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

The format string

```
" %[^\n]" 
 ^ note the leading space
```

means that `scanf` will first read and discard any number of leading whitespace characters and then match any sequence of characters which does contain a newline. `scanf` can potentially overrun the buffer it save the string into if the input string is too large for the buffer invoking undefined behaviour. The `%s` format specifier means `scanf` skips the leading whitespace characters and reads the input string till it encounters a whitespace at which point it appends a terminating null byte to the buffer it writes into and then returns.

Therefore, what you need is

```
char array2[20][20];
int i;

for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    scanf("%19s", array2[i]);

for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    printf("%s\n", array2[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Can you help me out in knowing how to do this dynamically?